# Solve a linear ODE with dirac delta

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dirac-delta, bessel-functions

I have to solve this linear differential equation
$$
rf''(r) + f'(r) + k^2rf(r) = \delta(r)
$$
on $\mathbb{R}^+$.

I know the solutions to the homogeneous problem are $cJ_0(kr)+dY_0(kr)$, where $J_0,Y_0$ are the zeroth order Bessel functions are the first and second kind. But how do I go about solving the problem with this right hand side ?

For background, I'm trying to solve the partial differential equation $$\left(\Delta-\dfrac{1}{c^2}\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\right)A(r,t) = -\dfrac{\mu_0 i(t)}{2\pi r}\delta(r)$$ which reduces to what I have after Fourier transform w.r.t. time and fixing $\omega$, and setting $k=\omega/c$.

Comment: It's actually the electric field for a situation where there's a time-dependant current flowing through a wire on the line of equation $r=0$ (in cylindrical coordinates).

Comment: Already tried that. I get a differential equation that I can solve, but I'm not able to really Fourier transform back the solution.

Comment: Indeed, it leads the linear ODE, where $x$ is the Fourier transform variable w.r.t. r
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left((k^2-x^2)F(x)\right) - xF(x) = 1,
$$
which I change to $$G'(x) - \frac{x}{k^2-x^2}G(x) = 1 $$ with $G(x) = (k^2-x^2)F(x)$.

The solution of the homogeneous problem is $\sqrt{|k^2-x^2|}$, yes, but the particular solution is $\ln(\sqrt{x^2-k^2}+x)$ for $x>k$ and $\arctan(x/\sqrt{k^2-x^2})$ for $x<k$.

Performing the inverse Fourier transform of that doesn't sound very computable.

Answer (score 3):

For $r\neq 0$, the Dirac delta vanishes, and therefore
$$
f(r)=\begin{cases}c_1J_0(kr)+d_1Y_0(kr) & r<0\\
c_2J_0(kr)+d_2Y_0(kr) & r>0
\end{cases}
$$

The ODE, being of second order, should have solutions with *two* arbitrary coefficients; but the expression above apparently has *four* arbitrary constants. In fact, there are two equations that constraint these four constants, reducing the number down to two, as one would expect.

The two relations are
$$
f(0^-)=f(0^+)
$$
(why?) and
$$
\big[rf'(r)\big]^{0^+}_{0^-} = 1
$$
(why?)

Comment: My solution function isn't defined on the negative reals, though...

Comment: then you cannot have a delta at $r=0$. Maybe you want to solve $...=\delta(r-r_0)$?

Comment: The function is defined on $\mathbb R^+$: why can't I have a delta ?